# js is not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a simple form working in web but when it comes to mobile devices it doesn't work.

```
function validateForm() {

    var full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value;

    if (full_name == '') {
        alert("Please enter your full name.");
        return false;
    }

}


<form method="post" id="event-form" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name"   >
    <input type="submit" name="roles_reminder" value="submit" class="rolessubmit" id="rolessubmit">
</form>
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/yx5Mb/6/

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me

Comment: Yeah really weird...it works in the normal browser.Are you checking fiddle?There it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work in the fiddle

Comment: so fiddle has got a bug itself...lol

Comment: It works on my desktop but does not on jsfiddle.

Comment: Suman let's forget about fiddle..So if the code works in desktop then why not in mobile device.

Comment: Now it works in fiddle.-- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/yx5Mb/6/